# asp.net mvc 5 Jquery cascading dropdown populates textboxes

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have done an extensive search to get some guidance I have a dropdown list:

```
    <div class="form-group-sm">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) 
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CustomerId, new SelectList(ViewBag.CustomerList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control", id = "CustomerId" })
            @*<input id="test" type="text" />*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

...that cascades to this dropdown list:

```
<div class="form-group-sm">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShipToId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) 
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select id="ShipToId" name="ShipToId" class="form-control"></select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ShipToId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to take the ShipToId from the above and grab fields for the following textboxes (I won't list all of them here but with some guidance I can figure out how to fill mulitple fields):

```
<div class="form-group-sm">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" }) 
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "Address1" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following JQuery which populates my cascading dropdownlists for CustomerId and ShipToId:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Order/GetCustomerIds/' + $('#CustomerId option:selected').val(), function (data) {
        var items = '<option value="">Select ShipTo</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, ShipToIdSelectList) {
            items += "<option value='" + ShipToIdSelectList.Value + "'>" + ShipToIdSelectList.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("#ShipToId").html(items);
        //$(function () {
        //    $("#State").val(StateCode);
        //})
    })
})

$('#CustomerId').change(function () {
    $.getJSON('/Order/GetCustomerIds/' + $('#CustomerId').val(), function (data) {
        var items = '<option>Select ShipTo</option>';
        $.each(data, function (i, ShipToIdSelectList) {
            items += "<option value='" + ShipToIdSelectList.Value + "'>" + ShipToIdSelectList.Text + "</option>";
        });
        $("#ShipToId").html(items);
    })
})
```

The cascade is working fine.  I also have a method that will take the ShipToId and bring back a list including the fields I need:

```
    var sta = (from o in db.Ord
               join s in db.ShipTo on o.ShipToId equals s.ShipToId
               where o.CompanyId == CurrentCompanyId && s.CustomerId == id
               select new
               {
                   ShipToId = o.ShipToId,
                   Name = s.Name,
                   Address1 = s.Address1,
                   Address2 = s.Address2,
                   Address3 = s.Address3,
                   Address4 = s.Address4,
                   City = s.City,
                   County = s.County,
                   Country = s.CountryCode,
                   State = s.StateCode,
                   PostalCode = s.PostalCode

               }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Result:

```
[0] = { ShipToId = "1~0", Name = "Big Head Productions", Address1 = null, Address2 = null, Address3 = null, Address4 = null, City = "Boonville", County = "...", Country = "US", State = "..." ... }
```

I have the information I need I just not sure how to use JQuery to fill in the correct text boxes.  I don't know this might be easier using a framework such as Angular or Knockout.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you would need another change event for the #ShipToId drop down.

on change call another method that gets the shipping info.  this would also mean that the first time around you wouldn't need to return all of the shipping info, just the info needed to build the drop down.  So if someone has a "Home" and a "Work" address, you would just return the id and the description to populate the drop down and then use the id to retrieve the shipping info.

Its up to you if you want the shipping info populated on load, like it seems that you are doing for the first two drop downs.

Comment: I think this is the correct.  I will mark your answer as correct if it is and if not I will provide my answer